# docker compose wont build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using docker-compose to build against an existing dockerfile with some slight changes fails with:

```
Step 1/10 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> 055936d39205
Step 2/10 : LABEL MAINTAINER="Peter Winter <peter@pwntr.com>"     Description="Simple and lightweight Samba docker container, based on Alpine Linux."     Version="1.0.2"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e99eafd27cc6
Step 3/10 : RUN apk --no-cache upgrade && apk --no-cache add samba samba-common-tools supervisor
 ---> Running in 99c71d23252f
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: could not connect to server (check repositories file)
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: could not connect to server (check repositories file)
OK: 6 MiB in 14 packages
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: could not connect to server (check repositories file)
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: could not connect to server (check repositories file)
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  samba (missing):
    required by: world[samba]
  samba-common-tools (missing):
    required by: world[samba-common-tools]
  supervisor (missing):
    required by: world[supervisor]
ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: Service 'samba' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk --no-cache upgrade && apk --no-cache add samba samba-common-tools supervisor' returned a non-zero code: 3
```

Appears to be not using the proxy?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  samba:
    #image: pwntr/samba-alpine
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: samba
    volumes:
      - /some/path:/shared:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I have tried setting the args and environment sections with the proxy details, however makes no difference.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  samba:
    #image: pwntr/samba-alpine
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
#      args: # Environment variables available at build-time
#        - http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
#        - https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
#        - HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
#        - HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
#    environment: # Environment variables available at container run-time
#      - http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
#      - https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
#      - HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
#      - HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
    container_name: samba
    volumes:
      - /some/path:/shared:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
```

If I use `docker run`  or via image everything works fine.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  samba:
    image: pwntr/samba-alpine
    container_name: samba
    volumes:
      - /some/path:/shared:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Server/Host is running Alpine Linux with connections working fine.

```
docker info | grep -i proxy
HTTP Proxy: http://127.0.0.1:3128/
HTTPS Proxy: http://127.0.0.1:3128/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else has the issue.

Run `ifconfig` and find the IP address of `docker0`

Edit `cntlm.conf` and add the following

`Listen 172.17.0.1:3128` # IP address of docker0

Restart `cntlm`

Create config file at `/root/.docker/config.json` and add the following

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://172.17.0.1:3128",
     "httpsProxy": "http://172.17.0.1:3128",
     "ftpProxy": "http://172.17.0.1:3128"
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`docker build -t localhost/smb:v1 .`

You better change `RUN apk --no-cache upgrade && apk --no-cache add samba samba-common-tools supervisor` to `RUN apk --no-cache --upgrade add samba samba-common-tools supervisor` to avoid multiple network requests.

Comment: Environment variables only take effect on the command line, not APK, such as yum, you need to set /etc/yum.conf, apk is the same.

Comment: I tried ```docker build -t localhost/smb:v1 .``` still produces the same error.

My env vars are already set otherwise nothing would work right?

```
env | grep -i proxy
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
```
I've been at this for a couple of days it really has me beat :(

Comment: Try global settings,like
 ```

RUN echo 'export http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:3128' >> /etc/profile
RUN echo 'export https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:3128' >> /etc/profile

```
'x.x.x.x' must be an address that is reachable from inside the container.

Comment: no go... I am certainly at a loss :/

What I don't understand is that if I just use the ```image: pwntr/samba-alpine``` in the compose file it works. Isn't that accessing the my proxy from inside the container as well?

Comment: If you use a fixed `image:` it doesn't go off and rebuild it, it just downloads the built image from Docker Hub (or some other registry).